# magento2 setup error with database MariaDB?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

today I uninstall mysql and add new  mysql-5.6.27-winx64, Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive  in https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/. and add pubbin mariaDB in Zendserver. 
[image]

when i setup magento2 magento2-1.0.0-beta to  Step 2: Add a Database click button Next do nothing.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing Magento via CLI? That might give you a better understanding and maybe an error to start debugging. Also, no errors on the browser console?

Comment: no errors on the browser console.

Comment: @xanka try to install using Magento via CLI. also did you setup a password for you db root user.

Comment: I tried install using Magento via CLI. It's success. why install magento2 in web setuo winzard has problem.